# Select All rows and it's count in a single query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some table called items and want to get some rows from it and count(all) in a single query, right now I'm trying something like this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) as count,
  (SELECT * FROM items WHERE ...) as items
FROM items
```

But I got **subquery must return only one column** error

Items table:

```
Id| Comment
1 | "comment1"
2 | "comment2"
3 | "comment3"
4 | "comment4"
5 | "comment5"
```

I want to have something like this in a result:

```
[{
  count: 5,
  items: [
   {
     id: 1,
     comment: "comment1"
   }
   ...other 4 comments
  ]
}]
```

What is s good way to do this?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  If you only care about `items`, why is your query referring to `notes`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm sorry, there was a mistake, no notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query(Postgres 9.5 and Above):

```
select 
json_agg(d) 
from 
(SELECT count(*) as "Count", json_agg(t) as "Items" 
FROM (select * from items) t
) d
```

[DB-Fiddle Example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sLAVT2rNUr1mWEhz1HgSoY/4)

Comment: thanks for posting the db-fiddle link

Answer (score 1):

If you want rows from items along with the count, you can use window functions:

```
select i.*, count(*) over () as num_items
from items i;
```

Comment: is there any way to have count as a separate field, not in every row?

Comment: @RomanSereda That's too unspecific. You should edit your question and add sample input and expected output, as suggested by GordonLinoff (the answer will depend on the DDL of your table or the columns you want in your result).

Comment: @FrankSchmitt sorry for that, i have updated my question